# Flutter - firebase_ml_vision - doesn't build on IOS - textRecognizer doesn't work

Tags: flutter, firebase-machine-learning

Flutter - Trying to get  `textRecognizer` to work on IOS

`firebase_ml_vision` - doesn't build on IOS

pubspec.yaml:

```
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0+1
  firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
  firebase_ml_vision: ^0.10.0
```

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    # Can be removed when moving to cocoapods 1.10
    config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER'] = 'NO'
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # Inherit the deployment target defined in this Podfile instead, e.g. platform :ios, '11.0' at the top of this file
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```

running `flutter build ios`

```
 <module-includes>:1:1: error: umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include header 'GDTCORPrioritizer.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    #import "Headers/GoogleDataTransport-umbrella.h"
    ^
    <module-includes>:1:1: error: umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include header 'GDTCORRegistrar.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: error: umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include header 'GDTCORStorageEventSelector.h'
    [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: error: umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include header 'GDTCORPlatform.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: error: umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include header 'GDTCORStorageProtocol.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: error: umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include header 'GDTCORUploader.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: error: umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include header 'GDTCORAssert.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: error: umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include header 'GDTCORLifecycle.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: error: umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include header 'GDTCORReachability.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    <module-includes>:1:1: error: umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include header 'GDTCORUploadPackage.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    10 errors generated.
    In file included from /Users/user924432/work/zapit/zapit/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/Firebase/CoreDiagnostics/FIRCDLibrary/FIRCoreDiagnostics.m:20:
    /Users/user924432/work/zapit/zapit/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/Internal/GoogleDataTransportInternal.h:18:9: fatal error:
    could not build module 'GoogleDataTransport'
    #import <GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    While building module 'GoogleUtilities' imported from
    /Users/user924432/work/zapit/zapit/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/Firebase/CoreDiagnostics/FIRCDLibrary/FIRCoreDiagnostics.m:22:
    <module-includes>:1:1: error: umbrella header for module 'GoogleUtilities' does not include header 'GULLoggerCodes.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    #import "Headers/GoogleUtilities-umbrella.h"
    ^
    1 error generated.
    12 errors generated.
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

Tried `pod update`

```
FF035:ios user924432$ pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories

CocoaPods 1.10.1 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.10.1

Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_ml_vision: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Downloading dependencies
Installing AppAuth (1.4.0)
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.7)
Installing DKImagePickerController (4.3.2)
Installing DKPhotoGallery (0.0.17)
Installing FMDB (2.7.5)
Installing Firebase (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (7.7.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (7.7.0)
Installing FirebaseMLCommon (7.6.0-beta)
Installing FirebaseMLVision (7.3.0-beta)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseStorage (7.3.0)
Installing Flutter (1.0.0)
Installing GTMAppAuth (1.1.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.5.0)
Installing GoogleAPIClientForREST (1.5.1)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (8.1.0)
Installing GoogleSignIn (5.0.2)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.3.1)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.2.2)
Installing Mantle (2.1.6)
Installing PromisesObjC (1.2.12)
Installing Protobuf (3.14.0)
Installing SDWebImage (5.10.4)
Installing SDWebImageWebPCoder (0.8.3)
Installing SwiftyGif (5.4.0)
Installing abseil (0.20200225.0)
Installing camera (0.0.1)
Installing cloud_firestore (0.16.0-1)
Installing device_info (0.0.1)
Installing esys_flutter_share (0.0.1)
Installing file_picker (0.0.1)
Installing firebase_auth (0.20.1)
Installing firebase_core (0.7.0)
Installing firebase_messaging (8.0.0-dev.15)
Installing firebase_ml_vision (0.1.1)
Installing firebase_storage (7.0.0)
Installing flutter_exif_rotation (0.3.0)
Installing flutter_html_to_pdf (0.0.1)
Installing flutter_image_compress (0.0.1)
Installing gRPC-C++ (1.28.2)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.28.2)
Installing geolocator (6.2.0)
Installing google_sign_in (0.0.1)
Installing image_picker (0.0.1)
Installing leveldb-library (1.22)
Installing libwebp (1.2.0)
Installing nanopb (2.30906.0)
Installing native_device_orientation (0.0.1)
Installing path_provider (0.0.1)
Installing pdf_render (0.0.1)
Installing permission_handler (5.1.0+2)
Installing receive_sharing_intent (0.0.1)
Installing share (0.0.1)
Installing shared_preferences (0.0.1)
Installing sqflite (0.0.2)
Installing url_launcher (0.0.1)
Installing z_ocr (0.0.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 27 dependencies from the Podfile and 62 total pods installed.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

[!] The `Runner [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Runner [Release]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Runner [Profile]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] FirebaseMLCommon has been deprecated

[!] FirebaseMLVision has been deprecated
FF035:ios user924432$
```

Answer (score 0):

solved:

```
pod deintegrate
pod update
flutter clean
flutter build ios
```

NOTE: although it compiles it still doesn't work - see https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5174

> If you're using one of the on-device APIs, include the corresponding
> ML Kit library model in your Podfile. Then run pod update in a
> terminal within the same directory as your Podfile.
>
> FYI this will currently run into #4625 Thank you

see https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4625

I was able to get textRecognizer to work on ios with the following:

pubspec.yaml

```
  firebase_core: "^0.5.0"
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.1+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.1+1
  firebase_storage: ^5.0.0-dev.2
  firebase_ml_vision: ^0.9.10
```

Podfile

```
pod 'Firebase/MLVision'
# If using an on-device API:
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionTextModel'
```

Comment: While commands may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.